# What's the most efficient way to locate and set element values in an XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML 'template':

```
<Request module="CRM" call="list_service_features" id="{ID}">
  <block name="auth">
     <a name="username" format="text">{USERNAME}</a>
     <a name="password" format="password">{PASSWORD}</a>
     <a name="client-id" format="counting">{CLIENT-ID}</a>
  </block>
  <a name="service-id" format="counting">{SERVICE-ID}</a>
</Request>
```

Using XDocument, what's the best way to set the values in curly braces. I got so far but got stuck on the best way to select each of the three `<a />` nodes inside the `<block/>` element. This is just a small fragment of XML, others may have up to 20 `<a name="..."></a>` elements.

The the way the XML is constructed wasn't my creation, it's what we have to sent to our supplier's 'web service'...before anyone has a laugh at the format="counting" attribute :)

[@David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299747/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-locate-and-set-element-values-in-an-xdocument#299887) - cheers for the response, appreciated. I was kinda hoping it'd be a bit more elegant, kinda along the lines of:

```
List<XElement> e = doc.Descendants("a").ToList();
e.Where(x => x.Attributes("name") == "username").Single().Value = "abc";
e.Where(x => x.Attributes("name") == "password").Single().Value = "abc";
```

Clearly the code above doesn't work but I thought there would be an elegant one liner for each of the `<a>` tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do it for you?  Good old Descendants property.

```
string xmlInput = ...;
XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlInput);
//
List<XElement> someElements = myDoc.Descendants("a").ToList();
someElements.ForEach(x => x.Value = "Foo");
//
Console.WriteLine(myDoc);
```

Hmm, I see you have an attribute in there.  Can do that too:

```
string xmlInput = //...
XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlInput);
//
List<XText> someText =
  myDoc.Descendants()
  .Nodes()
  .OfType<XText>()
  .Where(x => x.Value.StartsWith("{") && x.Value.EndsWith("}"))
  .ToList();
//
List<XAttribute> someAttributes =
  myDoc.Descendants()
  .Attributes()
  .Where(x => x.Value.StartsWith("{") && x.Value.EndsWith("}"))
  .ToList();
//
someText.ForEach(x => x.Value = "Foo");
someAttributes.ForEach(x => x.Value = "Bar");
//
Console.WriteLine(myDoc);
```

Ah, now with what you're expecting, I will make it work:

```
List<XElement> e = myDoc.Descendants("a").ToList();
e.Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "username").Single().Value = "abc";
e.Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "password").Single().Value = "abc";
```

Comment: Yep that's what I'm looking for. I arrived at something similar but more clunky: e.Attributes("name").Where(a => a.Value == "username").Single().Parent.Value = "abcdef";   Much appreciated!