# How do I replace only a specific value in an XML document without changing anything else?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex, string

I've been trying to replace a specific value from an xml document in memory before creating a message log of the XML.

I've managed to do a replace, but the Regex replace method seems to replace other items as well.

I've had to make this a little more funky than I would have liked but the elements within the document can contain different XML namespaces...

```
string pattern = "(<).*?(ElementName>).*?(<\\/).*?(ElementName>).*?";

string replacementPattern = "(<).*?(ReplacedElementName>)xxxxxxxxxxxxxx(<\\/).*?(ReplacedElementName>).*?";

string messageToLog = Regex.Replace(messageToSanitise, pattern, replacementPattern);
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

[Update 16:11 BST 09/08/2013]

Thanks Dash, I tried to do that, but then I realised that the object Contains an xml and isn't actually an xml document itself, looks like the object has some headers, with the xml is within a document envelope. Ideally I don't want to lose any information (including the headers) before logging. There will always be 1 or 2 occurences of the element I am trying to change never more and never less than 1.

Comment: It's better to load your XML into an XMLDocument or an XDocument and replace the value through the DOM. That way you can specify exactly the value to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks Dash, I  tried to do that, but then I realised that the object Contains an xml and isn't actually an xml document itself, looks like the object has some headers, with the xml is within a document envelope. Ideally I don't want to lose any information (including the headers) before logging. There will always be 1 or 2 occurences of the element I am trying to change never more and never less than 1.

Comment: If the `xml` is in a property on the object, then grab the xml string from that property, load it into an `XDocument`, and then set the property with the `.ToString()` of the `XDocument` afterwards. If you still want to use the RegEx approach, then I suggest you look at the Matches collection - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx - so you can look at each match in turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your xml is in the string `messageToSantise`, you can try the following:

**Using XmlDocument:**

(classic XML parsing common in older versions of the framework, and your only choice on older versions)

```
XmlDocument messageDoc = new XmlDocument();
messageDoc.Load(messageToSanitise);
messageDoc.SelectSingleNode(path_to_node).Value = replacementValue
```

`path_to_node` can be used with the appropriate [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) expression.

To get the xml string back out of the XmlDocument, use the `messageDoc.OuterXml` property.

```
string messageToLog = messageDoc.OuterXml;
```

**Using XDocument:**

(xml parsing via a LINQ style mechanism, supported in new versions of the framework)

```
XDocument messageDocument = new XDocument();
messageDocument.Parse(messageToSanitise);
messageDocument.Element(path_to_element).value = replacementValue;
```

To navigate through an XDocument, you may wish to also use the `Descendents` property. Examples of how to arrive at the node include this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299747/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-locate-and-set-element-values-in-an-xdocument?rq=1) and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx) here.

To get the Xml from the XDocument, use `messageDocument.ToString();`

```
string messageToLog = messageDocument.ToString();
```

This allows you to specify exactly what you want to replace.

If you want to decide whether to use XmlDocument or XDocument, I recommend reading the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1542101/1073107).